# Cancelling group of threads if one of the thread finishes

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to figure out the solution for a scenario of cancelling a group of threads if one of the Thread finishes the task successfully.

The scenario is like this: Lets say a group of threads are working on a task to find a String in a file and if any of the thread finds the String, the remaining treads should stop execution.

Using 1.5 concurrency we can achieve this, but prior to JDK 1.5 if we want to achieve this kind of scenario, then how can we do that?

Comment: Maybe you could tell us how you achieve it with 1.5 concurrency and why you can't achieve it in < 1.5.

Comment: Have you thought of interrupting the other threads ? i.e. invoke the interrupt method on the other threads

Answer (score 0):

For Java 2 Platform, Standard Edition 1.4 SDK or higher you could use [exception chaining](http://www.forward.com.au/javaProgramming/threadReturnsPackage/ToCatchAThread.html#threadlisteners).

Answer (score 0):

How about just splitting up the thread's task into smaller chunks and checking for a `stop` condition in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

The good way to stop a thread is to have it periodically check a flag that indicates whether or not it should continue. The java Thread class already has such a facility, called interrupts, that is useful in many scenarios, as bennihepp points out in his answer. See the javadoc for the [Thread class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) and the [interrupt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) and [isInterrupted()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) methods in particular.

In the following example the runnable class makes sure that all of the instances halt (soon) after one instance finishes. It is worth noting that you should keep your unit of work (one iteration of the loop) small enough.

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
  private static boolean shouldStop = false;

  public void run() {
    // allocate required resources
    while (!MyRunnable.shouldStop) {
      // do work

      if (/* some condition to indicate completion */)
        MyRunnable.shouldStop = true;
    }
    // release any allocated resources
  }
}
```

This simple example assumes all threads wrap the same type of a runnable object. Once one sets the `shouldStop` flag, all others also stop. It would be quite trivial to extend the example to also facilitate interruptions.

Answer (score 0):

You could interrupt the threads and in each thread check for the interrupted flag:

```
public class Job implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            // perform stuff
        }
    }

}
```

In the shutdown-code you call

```
thread.interrupt();
```

for each other thread.

The advantage compared to a stop-flag is that your threads will also drop out of any blocking calls.